# G is a group, N is an abelian subgroup of G. Does it means Z(N)=N?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

G is a group, N is an abelian subgroup of G. Does it means $C_G (N)=N$? Just wanna make sure, can anyone give a counterexample?

Comment: $Z(N)=N$ for all abelian groups, in particular for abelian subgroups of other groups.

Comment: Do you talk about the *center* of $N$ or about the *centralizer* of $N$ within $G$? The former does not care about $G$ ...

Comment: Yes I'm so sorry, I mean what Hagen von Eitzen said

Comment: For example if $G$ is an abelian group then the centralizer of any subgroup will be the whole group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Yes this is true, if by $Z(N)$ you denote the center of $N$.

The center of an abelian group (or subgroup) will always be itself.

- If you are talking about the centralizer

$$C_G(N)=\{g\in G, \ gn=ng\ \forall n\in N\}$$

this is not true.

**Edit**

Since you edited your question to clarify, I will give a counterexample for what you are looking for.

Take $G$ a group, and $N=\{e\}$ where $e$ is the identity element of $G$.

Then $C_G(N)=G\ne N$, but $N$ is abelian.

Comment: yes it's what i meant, can you give me an example

Comment: Thank you for a simple example